# Routing specific web sites through wifi

Tags: mac, routing, routing-table

I am using Macbook and it's connected to office Ethernet and wifi (Mobile hotspot). Few website like - *https://firebase.google.com/* don't work properly through office ethernet I need to switch to mobile hotspot.

*I have very little network knowledge I could not find any step by step solution to do so.*

**I was thinking is there any way to open few website through wifi only?**

Comment: Its probably not easily possible to route some websites via Wifi - but what you can do is route some IP addresses via WIFI, which effectively does the same thing - provided the IP address does not change, and with the side effect of routing any other sites using that IP address through wifi as well.   I don't use a MAC so I can't advise the exact command but it will be something like "route add -host X.X.X.X --interface WIFIIFNAME

Comment: so in this case X.X.X.X will be the ip address of https://firebase.google.com/ ?

Comment: @davidgo WIFIIFNAME mean the name of the wifi (Mobile Hotspot name) ?

Comment: No, WIFINAME would be either the IP address of the Hotspot or the name of the WIFI interface on your MAC.  You can probably deduce this from doing a 'netstat -nr' and looking for other IP addresses routed out that Interface.

Comment: Also, while X.X.X.X would be the IP address of "firebase.google.com", when it comes to sites hosted at big providers you need to be very careful as there is usually more then 1 IP address associated with a site.  You might want to add a line in your hosts file to map the domain name to the IP address (but this can break if Google update their site)

Comment: @davidgo thanks for the clarification. Can you tell me where can I get the ip address of a site like firebase.google.com

Comment: Its fraught with issues and limitations, but if you open a shell  and type "ping firebase.google.com" it will come back with an IP address you can use.  (I can't give you a good address because I'm in NZ, so the one I get points to their data center in Sydney)